# POST parameters on REST api - links or inline?

Tags: rest, design-patterns

I am trying to design a rest api and i have a resource with links to another resource. say

```
GET /resource1/id1

{
  "property1": "value1",
  ...
  "links" : [
    {
       "rel": "res1to2rel",
       "href": "/resource2/r2"
    }
  ]
```

now on a post to create resource1, i want to pass a relationship to resource2. should the POST call look like

```
POST /resource1

{
  "res1to2rel": "/resource/r2"
}
```

or should it look like

```
POST /resource1

{
  "links" : [
    {
      "rel": "res1to2rel",
      "href": "/resource2/r2"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the best practice, should the POST match the GET or can it have properties that you dont see on GET?

Comment: I think it will be easier in most cases if they match, but it isn't _required_ that they match.

Answer (score 0):

There're few absolute rules when it comes to REST design, but I think that it'd be easier for the client if a resource has a consistent set of representations. When you `POST` a representation, you typically create a new resource. This can be made even more explicit by:

1. Returning `201 Created`.
2. Returning a `Location` header in the response.
3. Returning a copy of the representation as the server sees it.

Thus, a `POST` might look like this:

```
POST /resource1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "property1": "value1",
  ...
  "links" : [
    {
       "rel": "res1to2rel",
       "href": "/resource2/r2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The response might then be:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Location: /resource1/id1

{
  "property1": "value1",
  ...
  "links" : [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "/resource1/id1"
    },
    {
       "rel": "res1to2rel",
       "href": "/resource2/r2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the server is allowed to enrich the resource, in the above example by adding a `"self"` link.

If a client later makes a `GET` request against the address supplied in that `LOCATION` header, it'll receive the same response as the echo it received from the `POST` request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "property1": "value1",
  ...
  "links" : [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "/resource1/id1"
    },
    {
       "rel": "res1to2rel",
       "href": "/resource2/r2"
    }
  ]
}
```

This makes it easier for clients to interact with the API because it can use the same internal model for reading and writing (i.e. serialising and deserialising) representations of a resource.